# Printing struct shows garbage

Tags: c

I´m trying to do a simple exercise where  should I should enter 2 inputs (monto and loc) in a struct using pointers and malloc. When I try yo print the data it shows garbage.  I tried to check what was happening so I print the data after entering and shows things like 
-1414812757 -158839287345460020000000000000000000000.00

```
struct transaccion{
    int loc;
    float monto;
    char nombre[50];
} cliente,*pcliente;

int cargadatos (struct transaccion*);
void mostrarlocalidad(struct transaccion*,int);
void mostrarestructura(struct transaccion*);

void main()
{
    int tam=50,ll;
    struct transaccion *pTrans;
    pTrans=(struct transaccion*)malloc(sizeof(struct transaccion)*tam);
    pTrans[0].monto=5;
    if(pTrans==NULL){
        puts("Falta memoria");
        exit(3);
    }

    ll=cargadatos(pTrans);
    mostrarlocalidad(pTrans,ll);
    free(pTrans);
    system("pause");
}

int cargadatos (struct transaccion *pTrans)
{
    int i=0;
    while (pTrans[i].loc!=0){
        puts ("ingrese numero de localidad");
        scanf("%d", &pTrans[i].loc); fflush (stdin);
        puts ("ingrese monto");
        scanf("%.2f",&pTrans[i].monto); fflush(stdin);
        int j=0;
        for (j=0; j<=i; j++)  {
            if (pTrans[j].loc==pTrans[i].loc){
                pTrans[j].monto=pTrans[j].monto+pTrans[i].monto;
                i--;
            }
        }
        printf("%d %.2f \n",pTrans[i].loc,pTrans[i].monto);
        i++;
    }
    return;
}
```

I´ve been trying many things for hours but I cant figure it out where are the errors.

Comment: `malloc` doesn't initialize the allocated memory block!

Comment: Who/what suggested using `fflush(stdin)`?

Comment: (1) `void main()` is wrong; (2) `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior; (3) you set `i` to `0`, decrement it in every loop, and then check whether or not `j <= i`, which will only be true on the first loop, then you try to print `pTrans[-1]`; (4) you don't `#include` any headers; (5) you call it "C++", yet you're using `malloc()` and `free()`; (6) etc etc etc, where did you get this weird stuff?

Comment: @chux it's a microsoft-specific hack to swallow newlines (the standards-compliant solution is to make the scan call itself swallow trailing space)

Comment: Side issue: `ll=cargadatos(pTrans);`, but `cargadatos(pTrans)` does not return a value, just a `return;`.

Comment: Lest we leave out the invalid conversion specifier in the `scanf()` invoke: `%.2f` ??

Comment: @WhozCraig: We might as well point out `pTrans[0].monto=5; if(pTrans==NULL) {...` checking for successful memory allocation *after* assigning to it if we're going down that route...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're seeing garbage is because your j loop is wrong.  Since you are iterating through <= i, your check will always be true.  In the first entry, you're checking pTrans[j].loc==pTrans[i].loc with both i and j being 0.  Therefore you set the values of j to itself, and decrement i.  When your printf runs, you're printing pTrans[-1] and not pTrans[0] as you probably are thinking you're doing.

Your easiest fix is to change your j loop to be j < i and not j <= i.  That way it won't ever run against itself which seems silly anyway.

Comment: Just changing to `j < i` is unlikely to be a "fix". There's an outer loop there which at least attempts to increment `i`, so the check is intended to only be true on the first iteration through that outer loop. Obviously the code is totally broken, decrementing `i` in the inner loop and then trying to increment it by 1 in the outer loop is almost certainly not going to lead to the desired behaviour, the `printf()` may be wrong after the first iteration as you say, the whole thing is never initialized, etc etc etc.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the check is intended to only be true on the first interation."  Given what he is trying to do, which is to add just-entered values to previously-entered values then throwing out the entry just added, the bug is checking the data he just entered against itself.  You NEVER want the j loop to hit the current entry, so j < i will definitely prevent that bug.  Initialization is a non-issue in the exact code we are looking at (but obviously is a problem for other reasons).

Comment: Unclear wording on my part, perhaps, but `j <= i` is guaranteed to be true when and only when `i <= 0`, which it is on the first iteration of the outer loop, but may not be on subsequent iterations due to the `i++` at the end of the `while` loop. The fact that `i` may get decremented in the `for` loop makes `i` go all over the place, so the `for` loop condition may be met a long time before you get to the data that was entered, i.e. `i` at the point of entry and `i` at the point the `for` loop condition is checked may not be the same.

Comment: j is a loop counter.  Assuming everything was working correctly, j would always be <= i every loop through the outer while loop.  If everything works correctly, there are never multiple instances of the same value (because the --i overwrites the value you just entered).  I think you're extrapolating errors out a bit too far.

Comment: If you do `j = 0` and `i = 0` and then you go `i--`, then `j <= i` will *not* be true, even if you didn't go `j++` at each loop iteration, which you do (or, rather, the OP does). During subsequent iterations of the outer loop, it *might* be true, because `i` might not start out at `0` due to the `i++` at the end of the outer loop. I don't feel any urge to explain this elementary math any further.

Comment: You're completely missing my point, so I guess we're at an impasse.  However, if you flow through the code with j < i instead of j <= i, what he is trying to do makes much more sense and will, in general, work.  The whole point is you don't WANT the j loop to run against the just-entered data.

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems here caused by the same mistake - a wrong condition on the j loop.
What I  assume you are trying to do is read into an array element, and
scan all previous array elements and see if you already have something at that location-in which case you want to use the "old" element for the count and then reuse the new element.
Now the range on the j loop being wrong will cause 3  problems:

1. You will ALWAYS read into element 0.
2. You will ALWAYS have the monto double what it should be
3. You will ALWAYS print array element [-1] which is not initialized and not what you ever intended.

This happens because when i=0, your j (being <=0)  will compare pTrans[0].loc==pTrans[0].loc.
As this is always true, you will now double your pTrans[0].monto (not what you  expect) giving a wrong result to start with.

Now i is decremented in an attemp to reuse it - making i==-1.

You now print this, uninitialized, unexpected [-1] element giving you whatever happens to be in that memory location.
Now you get hit by a third effect - you increment i making it 0, and iterate the while with the 0 element again.
ALL this is the result of one small mistake: using the condition j<=i in the j loop.
If you change this to

```
for (j = 0 ; j < i ; j++)
```

your program will probably work ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct transaccion{
    int loc;
    float monto;
    char nombre[50];
} cliente,*pcliente;
```

You declared two variables that you don't use anywhere.

```
pTrans=(struct transaccion*)malloc(sizeof(struct transaccion)*tam);
```

Casting from malloc is not necessary.

the following block should be placed *before* you use the pointer.

```
if(pTrans==NULL){
    puts("Falta memoria");
    exit(3);
}
```

This loop may or may not be executed, depending on the random value you will find in the specified memory area.

```
while (pTrans[i].loc!=0){
```

What is said in the other answers remains true as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to everyone, now I realized that I made way to much mistakes. Also I know that there variables I´m not using its because of thing I didn't implement yet. I'll correct it and post the working code.